# Azure mobile services password when deployed to IIS

Tags: azure, iis, publish, azure-mobile-services, iis-10

I published azure mobile service project in local IIS 10. But when prompted to access the url from a different machine, browser asks for an username and password.

On publishing it in azure, I use the application\master key as password and can access the api from any machine.

But while trying to access api from other machine by hosting in IIS, I am not having an application\master key.

Please help

Comment: Found it. its available in the config file. Not sure how to close this question as it is no longer an issue for me.

Comment: Please mark the below answer as accepted answer as it providing the solution you found and to close the question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that by the `Web.config` file:

```
<add key="MS_ApplicationKey" value="YOUR_KEY_HERE" />
```